# Scaling right vector based on light direction

Tags: c#, math, vector, 3d, unity-game-engine

I'm having a quad that I constructed and I would like to scale the quad based on how much light, the problem is the dot product gives me negative values, which I can not use to scale the vectors on the other side of the quad. I have a mesh consists of 6 vertices, two quads. One of the two quads should extend or shrink based on how much is the dot product values, how would I scale one quad and shrink the other side based on that dot product value ?

```
 float lightAngleRightVector = Vector3.Dot(lightDir.normalized, Source.transform.right.normalized);

        lightAngleRightVector = Mathf.Clamp(lightAngleRightVector, 0.2f, 0.5f);
        Global.Log("Light Angle Right Vecotr" + lightAngleRightVector);
        // light projected left side, limit values);
        if (lightAngleRightVector < 0.3f)
        {
            vxAbLeft = lightAngleRightVector;
            vxCdRight = lightAngleRightVector - 0.1f;
        }

        // light projected right side
        else if (lightAngleRightVector > 0.3f)
        {

            vxCdRight = lightAngleRightVector;
            vxAbLeft = lightAngleRightVector - 0.1f;
        }



        Global.Log("VxCDRIGHT =   " + vxCdRight);
        Global.Log("vxAbLeft =   " + vxAbLeft);

        // add little bit shift up for fixing z-fighting
        Vector3 vxPos1Top = (frontPt + new Vector3(0, mShadowOffestY, 0)) - (mRightFrontPt * vxAbLeft) * scale; // 1,2 vertices or on its left

        Vector3 vxPos2Top = (mRightBackPt * vxAbLeft) * scale;

        Vector3 vxPos3Top = frontPt;

        Vector3 vxPos4Top = backPt;

        Vector3 vxPos5Top =(mRightFrontPt * vxCdRight) * scale; // 5,6 vertices are on the right of the car

        Vector3 vxPos6Top =(mRightBackPt * vxCdRight * scale);
```

Comment: If it's negative shouldn't it just be 0 when talking about light. A negative dot product means that the linear projection of one vector on the other is in the opposite direction. Take a look at the [graphical representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dot_Product.svg).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the scale should be abs( scale ), so it will be > 0 from the unlit side. Is that what you want?